scp connection refused
I did a clean install of ubuntu server 24.04 recently.  Now I'm able to ssh to my server just fine from my laptop, on my home network.  But if I try to scp any files from my local laptop to my server I'm getting a "connection refused lost connection" message.  I have the more verbose output below.  Does anyone see what the issue might be and can you suggest how to fix it?
code:
scp -vvvv /home/username/Downloads/Anaconda3-2024.02-1-Linux-x86_64.sh username@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:~/stuff/username_storage/installs/

output:
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host xxx.xxx.xx.xxx, user username, command scp -v -t ~/stuff/username_storage/installs/
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.7, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname xxx.xxx.xx.xxx is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/username/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/username/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xx.xxx] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: connect to address xxx.xxx.xx.xxx port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xx.xxx port 22: Connection refused
lost connection

Update:
As kos suggested in comments below, I tried scp the file again and then ran
sudo journalctl -n 50 --no-pager -xu ssh

here's the output I got:
May 28 04:12:14 server systemd[1]: Stopping ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit ssh.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A stop job for unit ssh.service has begun execution.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 10793.
May 28 04:12:14 server sshd[2199]: Received signal 15; terminating.
May 28 04:12:14 server systemd[1]: ssh.service: Deactivated successfully.
░░ Subject: Unit succeeded
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ The unit ssh.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
May 28 04:12:14 server systemd[1]: Stopped ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit ssh.service has finished
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A stop job for unit ssh.service has finished.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 10793 and the job result is done.
-- Boot xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --
May 28 23:03:46 server systemd[1]: Starting ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit ssh.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit ssh.service has begun execution.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 27383.
May 28 23:03:46 server sshd[3788]: Server listening on :: port 22.
May 28 23:03:46 server systemd[1]: Started ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit ssh.service has finished successfully
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit ssh.service has finished successfully.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 27383.
May 28 23:04:00 server sshd[3789]: Accepted password for username from xxx.xxx.xx.xxx port 49038 ssh2
May 28 23:04:00 server sshd[3789]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user username(uid=1001) by username(uid=0)
May 28 23:13:36 server sshd[4064]: Accepted password for username from xxx.xxx.xx.xxx port 47228 ssh2
May 28 23:13:36 server sshd[4064]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user username(uid=1001) by username(uid=0)

As petep suggested, I also tried
sudo ufw allow ssh

But I still get the same "connection refused" error as mentioned before.
update:
tried
scp -D 99 /home/username/Downloads/Anaconda3-2024.02-1-Linux-x86_64.sh username@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:~/stuff/username_storage/installs/

got error:
ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xx.160 port 22: Connection refused
lost connection

update:
I'm now including the full error message I get when trying to scp files from my local laptop to my server.  Something I noticed today with the error message is that my server's ip address is 192.168.50.122 but the error message keeps refering to 192.168.50.160.122.  Does that make sense?
code:
username@madeupname-Laptop:~/$ scp -vvvv /home/username/Downloads/Anaconda3-2024.02-1-Linux-x86_64.sh username@192.168.50.160.122:~/stuff/username_storage/installs/

error:
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host 192.168.50.160.122, user username, command scp -v -t ~/stuff/username_storage/installs/
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.7, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_addr: could not resolve name 192.168.50.160.122 as address: Name or service not known
debug1: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.50.160.122 is an unrecognised address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/username/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/username/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "192.168.50.160.122" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup 192.168.50.160.122:22
ssh: Could not resolve hostname 192.168.50.160.122: Name or service not known
lost connection

update:
DOH!  Somehow I added the .160 to my scp command (bang head here).  Thank you chatgpt for catching it.  Thank everyone for helping and suggesting I include the ip to make debugging easier.

I'd try and scp -D 99 instead of scp -vvv (it appears as though scp -vvv is interpreted as just scp -v?), however since you can SSH into the server, what does the server say? Can you attemp to scp a file, then SSH into the server, run journalctl -n 50 --no-pager -xu ssh and add the output to your question?

sudo ufw allow ssh

sudo ufw allow ssh

@kos I added the journalctl output from the script you suggested I run as an update above.  Does it give you any clues?

In a similar question someone else had to stop and restart SSH: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1515704/ssh-service-no-longer-automatically-starts-after-ubuntu-server-upgrade-to-22-04 BTW for my home network I hardly use the server so I plan on leaving it on 16.04 until support runs out. For my main rig I'm scouring all the problems people are having with 24.04 for a planned install soon.

Is the May 28 23:04:00 attempt the unsuccesful scp attempt and May 28 23:13:36 the succesful ssh attempt? If so no, it didn't complain about the scp attempt. I would try and run scp -D 99 to see if says something scp -v doesn't, just in case

By the way please don't censor IP addresses, especially if they're private IP addresses like 192.168.1.1, which aren't revealing at all; if you really have to please leave at the least the octets containing the host-identifying bits uncensored, as it can become impossible to go through your logs correctly if multiple addresses are involved. Please let me know if the scp -D 99 method revealed something else (I don't really expect that though), and also try WinEunuuchs2Unix's suggestion. At this point I'd also update both client and server, just in case.

@kos I tried the scp -D 99 suggestion and added the error message above as an update.  I also tried stopping, disabling, re-enabling, and restarting ssh as suggested, but I still get the same error when I try to scp.

Can you confirm those two attempts in the log are the first from scp and the second from ssh?

@kos something I'm noticing is that if I run sudo journalctl -n 50 --no-pager -xu ssh, and then try to scp, and run the journalctl again, there are no new entries.  It doesn't seem to be logging anything with the failed scp attempts.  But I'm still able to ssh in.

The error that you're getting from the scp -vvvv command is exactly what I'd expect in the case that there is not an ssh service listening on the host/port - that makes me wonder if the problem is somehow related to failed socket-based activation of the service?

@kos I added an update with the full ip addresses in the scp -vvvv error.  Something I noticed is that my server ip is 192.168.50.122 but the error keeps mentioning 192.168.50.160.122.  Does that ring any bells?

Your question will likely be closed as "not reproducible". Alternatively you can delete your question before that happens.

I hadn't gotten back to this because I didn't really know what to suggest, but the "no log entries" part kinda rang a bell about a possible IP mismatch, I should've written something about it :| glad you figured it out.
