SSH service no longer automatically starts after Ubuntu server upgrade to 22.04 LTS
I have a VPS running Ubuntu server 22.04 LTS which was recently upgraded from 20.04 LTS. Since the upgrade, the SSH service no longer automatically starts - it worked for 2+ years without any issue before that - when trying to connect using Putty I get "Network error: Connection refused". After some searching, I was able to log back thru the console and I see the following:

I was then able to get SSH back working by doing:
sudo systemctl stop ssh
sudo systemctl disable ssh
sudo systemctl enable ssh
sudo systemctl restart ssh

However, the issue would persist after the next Reboot. I have tried the following without success. Any help would be appreciated.

sudo apt install openssh-server –reinstall did not work.
sudo systemctl enable --now ssh did not work. Actually, it was already ENABLED.
sudo update-rc.d ssh enable did not work.
Firewall is up and running.
dpkg -l | grep openssh-server returned ii  openssh-server 1:8.9p1-3ubuntu0.7  amd64   secure shell (SSH) server, for secure access from remote machines
$ cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config returns the following:

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the KbdInteractiveAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via KbdInteractiveAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and KbdInteractiveAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server

Lastly, $ ls -l /etc/rc*.d/*ssh returns the following:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Apr 16  2021 /etc/rc2.d/S01ssh -> ../init.d/ssh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Apr 16  2021 /etc/rc3.d/S01ssh -> ../init.d/ssh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Apr 16  2021 /etc/rc4.d/S01ssh -> ../init.d/ssh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Apr 16  2021 /etc/rc5.d/S01ssh -> ../init.d/ssh

thanks,

Thanks for getting back to me. My case is slightly different since I cannot connect when SSH is "inactive" and the ssh.socket was already not running. I tried sudo systemctl disable ssh.socket anyway but it did not work.

I've got the same issue. Any further update on this?

Hi, unfortunately not.

Please update question with the output of cat /etc/systemd/system/sshd.service and cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

@rumlauf Claude.ai was very helpful for me. I had some mounts in /etc/fstab that were no longer valid and were causing the boot process to fail.
